# R: Accessing elements of a matrix using a separate coordinate matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix (expTrans) that is currently filled with zeros.  I have a second matrix (expCoor) where the second column is filled with column names and the third column is filled with row numbers. I want to use the coordinates in the second matrix to change some elements in the first matrix to 1's. When I use this code, R fills each row mentioned in each column mentioned with a 1 (the columns come out identical):

```
expTrans<-matrix(0, nrow(cashflows), ncol(dmat))
colnames(expTrans)<-substr(colnames(dmat),4,6)
expTrans[expCoor[,3],colnames(expenses)[expCoor[,1]]]<-1
```

Is there a way to change only the row and column specified by each coordinate without having to loop through the whole matrix?

Here is a simple example to illustrate what I am talking about:

```
> m<-matrix(0,ncol=10,nrow=10)
> colnames(m)<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")
> m
      a b c d e f g h i j
 [1,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [2,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [3,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [4,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [5,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [6,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [7,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [8,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [9,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[10,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> ind<-cbind(sample(1:10,10),sample(1:10,10), c("a","a","b","j","c","d","e", "a", "b", "b"))
> ind
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,] "4"  "8"  "a" 
 [2,] "2"  "9"  "a" 
 [3,] "9"  "3"  "b" 
 [4,] "3"  "1"  "j" 
 [5,] "7"  "4"  "c" 
 [6,] "10" "7"  "d" 
 [7,] "8"  "6"  "e" 
 [8,] "1"  "2"  "a" 
 [9,] "6"  "5"  "b" 
[10,] "5"  "10" "b" 
> m[as.numeric(ind[,1]),ind[,3]]<-1
> m
      a b c d e f g h i j
 [1,] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
 [2,] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
 [3,] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
 [4,] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
 [5,] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
 [6,] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
 [7,] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
 [8,] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
 [9,] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
[10,] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

I expected column a to have 3 1s (rows 4,2,8), column b to have 3 1s (rows 9,6,5), column c to have 1 1 (row 7), column d to have 1 1 (row 10), column e to have 1 1 (row 8) and column j to have 1 1 (row 3).

Comment: Can you provide a simplified example of your data? At the moment you have `expTrans` `cashflows` `dmat` `expenses` and `expCoor`. Are all these necessary to represent your problem? I can't figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: Also, you say the **2nd** column in `expCoor` contains your column names. Why then are you referencing `expCoor[,1]` instead of `expCoor[,2]` in your final line of code for the column indexing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method to use a two-column *numeric* matrix for either "[" or "[<-". If you wanted to do some sort of lookup for the column and rownames, that might be possible (if and only if you provided an appropriate reproducible example.

```
> expTrans<-matrix(0, 3,4);expTrans
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
> dmat <- matrix( c(1,3,4,2,2,2),ncol=3, byrow=TRUE);dmat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    4
[2,]    2    2    2
> colnames(expTrans)<- colnames(dmat); rownames(expTrans) <-rownames(dmat)
> expTrans[cbind(dmat[,2],dmat[,3] )] <- dmat[,1]
> expTrans
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    2    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    1
> ?'['
```

The solution to the amended question:

```
> m[cbind( as.numeric(ind[,1]), match( ind[,3], colnames(m) ) ) ] <- 1
> m
      a b c d e f g h i j
 [1,] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [2,] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [3,] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [4,] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [5,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
 [6,] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [7,] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
 [8,] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [9,] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[10,] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: OK. Solution provided. Remember ... _numeric_